# How do I set Session name with Cherrypy?

Tags: php, python, session, cherrypy

In PHP I would do it like this:

```
session_name("special_session_name");
```

So how do I do it with Cherrypy?
Just need to find exact equivalent for it.
PHP manual page:
https://www.php.net/session_name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the docs and the source most probably you have to set "tools.sessions.name" in your config file:

```
cherrypy.config.update({'tools.sessions.name': "special_session_name"})
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what I was looking for.
Here's how to do it in python:
cherrypy.config.update({'tools.sessions.name': "special_session_name"})